# How to subtract a column value with every value in another column (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two columns A and B. I want to subtract column B value with every value in column A and create a new column without using for-loop.

Below is my Dataframe

```
    A   B
0   5   3
1   3   2
2   8   1
```

Desired output

```
    A   B   C   D   E
0   5   3   2   3   4   
1   3   2   0   1   2
2   8   1   5   6   7

C = A - B[0]
D = A - B[1]
E = A - B[2]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using numpy's array [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/theory.broadcasting.html#array-broadcasting-in-numpy):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[5, 3, 8],
                   'B':[3, 2, 1]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame(df['A'].values[:, None] - df['B'].values, columns=['C', 'D', 'E'])

df = df.join(df2)
```

Result:

```
   A  B  C  D  E
0  5  3  2  3  4
1  3  2  0  1  2
2  8  1  5  6  7
```

**Explanation**:

```
>>> df['A'].values[:, None]

array([[5],
       [3],
       [8]])

>>> df['B'].values

array([3, 2, 1])
```

When subtracting them, numpy "stretches" `df['A'].values[:, None]` to:

```
array([[5, 5, 5],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [8, 8, 8]])
```

and `df['B'].values` to:

```
array([[3, 2, 1],
       [3, 2, 1],
       [3, 2, 1]])
```

and the result of subtraction is:

```
array([[2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [5, 6, 7]])
```

Comment: oh sweet! didnt know about the None aspect there. another learning point. thanks

Comment: I think it would be clearer to write np.newaxis instead of none, even though '(np.newaxis is None) == True'

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
d = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'A': {0: 5, 1: 3, 2: 8}, 'B': {0: 3, 1: 2, 2: 1}})
m = d.shape[0]
cols = [chr(67 + x) for x in range(m)]
d.join(pd.DataFrame(np.broadcast_to(d['A'], (m, m)).T - np.broadcast_to(d['B'], (m, m)), columns=cols))
```

Explanation: broadcast each series into a 3x3 matrix and subtracts them, make it into a dataframe and join it to original. The columns are auto-generated.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:
1. replicate column A, according to the length of the dataframe
2. convert B to a numpy array
3. Subtract B from A, which should get u ur subtraction per row
4. concat back to main data

```
temp = pd.concat([df.A]*len(df), axis=1).sub(df.B.to_numpy())
final = pd.concat([df,temp], axis=1).set_axis(['A','B','C','D','E'],axis='columns')
final

    A   B   C   D   E
0   5   3   2   3   4
1   3   2   0   1   2
2   8   1   5   6   7
```